# Jenkins - trigger job if one of other projects was pulled by SCM

Tags: build, jenkins, jobs

Is there a possibility to trigger some job only if one of couple of others job was build by SCM trigger?

For example:
1. Projects A, B, C are build by SCM trigger.
2. Project D will be build only if A or B or C was build. It should build only once even if all of the upstream project were build (A, B and C).

Comment: Assuming 'Job D' was built once already (triggered by one of the other Jobs), how do you know when it is time to build 'Job D' again?

Answer (score 0):

For job 'D', under Advanced project options, add quiet period (how long, experiment what works well). Also make build parametrized, and add parameter for SCM version. When triggering the build from other builds, use parametrized trigger plugin and give SCM version as parameter.

The idea here is, that when there are two identical builds queued, Jenkins will combine them, and build D just once.

This assumes version control support of Jenkins actually sets environment variable indicating the version (in A, B and C jobs), I'm not 100% sure of this.

If you get it to work otherwise, but you get multiple builds, experiment with "allow concurrent builds" checkbox in build D, I think it had some effect on this, one way or another.